# JSF 2 RI (Mojarra) and Tomahawk compatibility

Tags: jsf-2, compatibility, tomahawk, mojarra

I need to use **fileUpload** from Tomahawk because not provided by Jsf. 
I want to know if **Tomahawk** is 100% compatible with **Mojarra**

I dont' find this information on the web.

My version of **Mojarra (2.1.2)** and **tomahawk (1.1.11)**

Thanks,

Yoel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three builds of Tomahawk 1.1.11: One for JSF 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0. As long as you use the 2.0 build of 1.1.11 you should be able to use it on Mojarra 2.1.x. The Tomahawk site clearly states all of this.

**Edit:**
As requested:

- http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/index.html
- http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/index.html
- http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/index.html

And then look at the download page, noting the different variants of Tomahawk 1.1.11 available for download: http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html

Comment: Can you post the link please?

Comment: I just find an old compatibility matrix it's the reason I post the question ... http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/CompatibilityMatrix

Comment: Links added as requested. Consider the information in the first link as a baseline for the information provided in the 2nd and 3rd link. And you should have an "aha" moment when you see the download page.